# Crystal Report not refreshing data after using a different SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I have created two methods that allow to use advanced search to display the Logs table:

```
void GetLogs()
{
     DateTime start = GetFirstRecord();
     DateTime end = GetLastRecord();
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = con;
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Logs.LogID, Users.LastName, Users.FirstName, " +
         "Logs.LogType, Logs.Description, Logs.Timestamp FROM Logs INNER JOIN Users " +
         "ON Logs.UserID = Users.UserID";

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds, "Report");
     rptLogs report = new rptLogs();
     report.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "(local)", "database");
     report.SetDataSource(ds);
     report.SetParameterValue("Start", start);
     report.SetParameterValue("End", end);
     crvLogs.ReportSource = report;
     crvLogs.Refresh();

     con.Close();
}
```

and

```
void GetLogsByTimestamp()
{
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = con;
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Logs.LogID, Users.LastName, Users.FirstName, " +
         "Logs.LogType, Logs.Description, Logs.Timestamp FROM Logs INNER JOIN Users " +
         "ON Logs.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE Logs.Timestamp BETWEEN @Start AND @End";
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpStart.Value.Date;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpEnd.Value.Date;
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds, "Report");
     rptLogs report = new rptLogs();
     report.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "(local)", "database");
     report.SetDataSource(ds);
     report.SetParameterValue("Start", dtpStart.Value.Date);
     report.SetParameterValue("End", dtpEnd.Value.Date);
     crvLogs.ReportSource = report;
     crvLogs.Refresh();

     con.Close();
}
```

The first method loaded the Crystal Report properly inside the application. However, when I triggered the second method, only the parameter field values were being updated. The details of the report are still the same.

Am I missing something?

Comment: 1) Is "save data in the report" flagged? It is EVIL

Comment: 2) Does CommandText + CommandParameter work? Can you look at real query using SQL Profiler?

Comment: Yes, they are working perfectly.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco How do I turn it off?

Comment: Report - Preview - "save data in the report" flag (if integrated in Visual Studio); File - REPORT options (if you use stand-alone crystal reports)

Comment: How does the second method get triggered and does it cause the report to get refreshed/reloaded?

Comment: @EmanueleGreco Thanks, but the data are still the same after using the second method. I tried displaying a blank record using the SQL profiler, but the viewer is still displaying the old record.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I used the DateValueChanged event to trigger the second method. I even tried using the RefreshReport method but to no avail.

Comment: How are the date parameters entered? Do you have text boxes?

Comment: @campagnolo_1 From the second method, I used datetimepicker controls.

Comment: Humor me and try this code in your SELECT statement ....WHERE Logs.Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?"; and comment out the two parameter declarations that follow the SELECT statement. I just recently finished a Windows Form project where I was trying to use named parameters and it just wouldn't work. So I had to use the "?" instead and that worked.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I'm using a parameterized SQL statement. You need to two valid DateTime values for Start and End.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39430/discussion-between-campagnolo-1-and-abramlimpin)

Answer (score 1):

```
report.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "(local)", "database");
report.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Does your report also have a separate database connection in addition to the dataset you are pushing into it?

Comment: They are using the same database connection but with different tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
     con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Logs.LogID, Users.LastName, Users.FirstName, " +
     "Logs.LogType, Logs.Description, Logs.Timestamp FROM Logs INNER JOIN Users " +
     "ON Logs.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE Logs.Timestamp BETWEEN @Start AND @End";
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime);
 cmd.Parameters["@Start"].Value = dtpStart.Value.Date;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.DateTime);
 cmd.Parameters["@End"].Value = dtpEnd.Value.Date;
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds, "Report");
 rptLogs report = new rptLogs();
 report.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "(local)", "database");
 report.SetDataSource(ds);
 report.SetParameterValue("Start", dtpStart.Value.Date);
 report.SetParameterValue("End", dtpEnd.Value.Date);
 crvLogs.ReportSource = report;
 crvLogs.Refresh();

 con.Close();
```

The question still remains whether the second method actually gets triggered. If so, the error is in the SQL statement, if not, then the trigger is wrong.